# Excluding a Word in Regex Java | Mobile vision API |Text block

Tags: java, android

I made a simple license plate scanning application when i am scanning it only Detect a word "SINDH" not the above number like AFR-2020 it only detects "SINDH" an goes to Textblock
AFR-2020 is above "SINDH"

below is the regex how can i exclude SINDH

```
String REGEX = "[a-zA-z]{1,4}\\s*[-]*[0-9]{0,2}\\s*[-]*[0-9]{3,4}$"; 
    Pattern number; 
    Matcher matcher;
    text = mText.getValue();
```

Comment: You should use `"[a-zA-Z]{1,4}\\s*[-]*[0-9]{0,2}\\s*[-]*[0-9]{3,4}$"`

Comment: That's exactly the regex that didn't work for the OP? Must his regex match other formats for the number plates than *AFR-2020*?

Answer (score 0):

the following regex matches *AFR-2020* but not *SINDH*

```
String regex = "[A-Z]+\\-\\d+";
```

*matches at least one uppercase character followed by a* `-` *followed by at least one digit*